# Layout usage in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am new to android.

As far as I know, there are different layouts like the liner layout, the table layout, and some others.

I would like to know in which case what layout would be suitable.

I am unable to categorize the exact differences between the layouts.

Also, can someone please tell me what the specific meanings of the attributes like `fill_parent`, `wrap_parent` are?

Answer (score 1):

All layouts have specific uses. Read android.developers.com, fill parent means your view will cover whole screen area, wrap-content covers that much area that is occupied by the layout's child views. Match - parent takes area equal to its parent area.But using match parent is not good.

Answer (score 1):

What type of layout to use really depends on how the layout you are trying to build looks. If you have a simple layout of items one after another, a LinearLayout usually is the best choice. It's easy to work with, but the drawback is that you can't really customize the layout very much. All your views will just end up in a horizontal or vertical list. A RelativeLayout gives you a better way of adding Views that are right/left/top/bottom aligned compared to its parent view. And last but not least, the TableLayout is really great if you are building a grid of views.